# Python GUI - Calculator drop-down menu

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a basic integer calculator program that uses two entries, a combo box, two labels, and a button to do basic calculations, as shown in the images below. The combo box should have the options for addition,  subtraction, and multiplication, displayed as '+', '-', and '*' respectively.

Row 0 of the layout grid must contain an entry, the combo box and another entry in columns 0 through 2 respectively. There must also be a label somewhere displaying the result value, optionally preceded by an equals sign as shown in the images below. The button must contain the text 'Calculate'. You may assume only integers are entered into the entries.

The layout of Counter GUI is as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qALXz.jpg)

I dont have a problem creating a button calculator. My problem is how to get a working gui as shown in the image. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some effort, but here goes:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def left_side():
    """Left """
    global left_entry, right_entry, answer_label, integer_combo
    left_entry.get()

def right_side():
    """Right"""
    global left_entry, right_entry, answer_label, integer_combo
    right_entry.get()

def combo_calc():
    """Combobox basic Calculator"""
    global left_entry, right_entry, answer_label, integer_combo

    if integer_combo.get() == "+":
        answer_label['text'] = str(int(left_entry.get()) + int(right_entry.get()))
    elif integer_combo.get() == "-":
        answer_label['text'] = str(int(left_entry.get()) - int(right_entry.get()))
    elif integer_combo.get() == "*":
        answer_label['text'] = str(int(left_entry.get()) * int(right_entry.get()))

def main():
    """Runs the main GUI"""
    global left_entry, right_entry, answer_label, integer_combo

    window = Tk()
    integer_options = ["+", "-", "*"]
    integer_combo = Combobox(window,
                             values=integer_options)
    integer_combo.set("+")
    integer_combo.grid(row=0, column=1)
    left_entry = Entry(window)
    left_entry.grid(row=0, column=0)
    right_entry = Entry(window)
    right_entry.grid(row=0, column=2)
    calc_button = Button(window, text='Calculate', command=combo_calc)
    calc_button.grid(row=1, column=1)
    equals_label = Label(window, text="=")
    equals_label.grid(row=0,column=3)
    answer_label = Label(window)
    answer_label.grid(row=0, column= 4)

    window.mainloop()
main()
```